# Dual wi-fi on 1 adaptor

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, dual-band

How do I connect to more than one wifi network using one adaptor? I have a dual-band 802.11n adaptor and Windows 8. I know about netsh commands for making your own network, but how can I create a virtual adaptor so I can connect to a second network?

Comment: You mean you would like to connect simultaneously to two different networks on different bands?

Comment: No, although that might be nice in the future. I assume it's impossible, though.

Comment: So what exactly are you asking about?

Comment: I'm asking how to create a second, virtual Wi-Fi adapter that I can tell to connect to another network in the area.